# Comment flag icons not showing on mobile meta

Tags: bug, flags

Today I noticed that I can not flag a comment when browsing meta on my phone (android). The flag icon isn't showing at all, unless I change my browser to 'desktop view'. This option enables flagging, but makes the flag quite small.

[Picture of comments without flagging option on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46sZ6.png)

[Picture of flag appearing when switching to desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bErRG.png)

I am using Chrome 65.0.3325.109 with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Can totally relate, the mobile version of the site is really nice, with the flags it would be very very nice.

Comment: I was just looking at this... As far as I can tell, flagging comments has *never* been supported in the mobile theme; they've been disabled for at least five years at any rate. I expect at this point it's probably easier to just push forward with the responsive designs.

Comment: And [Allow flagging comments on mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213709) and [Why is mobile version of the site missing flag comment functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208670), and ...

Comment: @Shog9 Probably I never noticed the disabling because I had no reason to flag comments on mobile before (which is positive, I guess? cx) . I simply assumed that the flag icon would be there just like the upvote icon when I needed to flag something and then it wasn't. But I'll use my desktop view in the rare occassion of flagging, that's not a problem to me ^^  Thank you for the clarification.